# How to run an executable file without the EXE extension using a CMD script?

Tags: windows, command-line

The situation is that I have a portable application that needs to have a set environment variable. Otherwise it tries to set it's settings in the user program data dir.

To avoid running the executable in non-portable mode (to avoid allowing it to run without any parameters), I erased the file's ".exe" extension. But then I cannot run it, neither with the mouse (which I want) or through the `start` command.

Is there any way to run an executable file that has no ".exe" extension?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. If you accidentally deleted the .EXE extension, why can't you add it back? What's preventing you from doing so?

Comment: I've deleted it on purpose to not accidentally hit it so the program would run without any parameters. I want to be safe to only run the program with options at start.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes – simply entering the program's full filename usually works. (The `.exe` requirement only exists in the GUI shell.)

(It *might* be that the file needs *an* extension, though – so if you can't get `MyProgram` to run, rename it to `MyProgram.notexe` or `MyProgram.lol` and try again.)

Comment: This surprised me once, when I renamed a self-extracting Zip file from `.exe` to `.zip`, tried to open it through cmd.exe, and it *still* ran the self-extractor instead of opening WinZip.

Comment: I didn't know the trick with changing extension, that program might need some dummy one, thats not so intuitive. But anyway I encountered another bummer that is the application itself needs its main executable to have a strict name.

Comment: Anything that starts with `MZ` will be executed by cmd, check below

Answer (score 18):

Any file with any extension and first two bytes `MZ` will be treated like an EXE.

Try following:

1. Create a new `a.txt` file,
2. Type in it `MZ`, save it.
3. Open `cmd`, go to its folder,
4. Type `a.txt` and see the error message.

Replace `MZ` with `MS` and try again - this time notepad will run with file opened.

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows 10. It always shows `'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error

Comment: I've just tried at home with in Windows 10 Pro and it indeed shows an error `This version of D:\test.txt is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.` previously I used Windows 10 LTSB at work and it didn't work

Comment: It still works on my Windows 10 X64, the same example as above.

Comment: If you try to execute a file without any extension, it will throw a `'file' is not recognized` error.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to run process from file without the .exe extension. When I failed to do so from cmd.exe I give a try some powershell commands. Here is one:

[Start-Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)

The documentation says about Default syntax and UseShellExecute. With just:

```
Start-Process -FilePath .\my-program -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

the command uses UseShellExecute syntax and returns error about not associated application to that file type. To force the Default syntax I added parameter that the UseShellExecute doesn't have:

```
Start-Process -FilePath .\my-program -Wait -RedirectStandardError ./error.txt -NoNewWindow
```

My program was started and wrote output to the console. This was enough for me, because I needed it only for test purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If `PATHEXT` env contains `.exe` or `.EXE`, then no need for this suffix when running the program. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_values).